# A question about homomorphisms and the existence of a subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

On page 117 of (Corollary 4.6.12),

http://www.albany.edu/~mark/algebra.pdf

I'm not sure how/why the proof says that there exists "a unique subgroup of order 5." How did they come up with that conclusion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Next time, please, quote the text.

So you want to know why the group $\mathbf{Z}_{11}^{*}$ has a unique subgroup of order $5$.

It is well known that $\mathbf{Z}_{11}^{*} = \mathbf{Z}_{11} \setminus \{ 0 \}$ [is cyclic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Cyclic), of order $10$. Now [a cyclic group $G$ of order $n$ has exactly one subgroup $H$ of order $m$ for each divisor $m$ of $n$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group#Subgroups_and_notation). If $G = \langle a \rangle$, then $H = \langle a^{n/m} \rangle$.

In this particular case $\mathbf{Z}_{11}^{*} = \langle \bar{2} \rangle$, so the unique subgroup of order $5$ is $\langle \bar{2}^{2} \rangle = \langle \bar{4} \rangle$.

**PS** Perhaps it might be mentioned that *any* group of order $10$ (there are two isomorphism classes, cyclic and dihedral) has a unique subgroup of order $5$. It has one such subgroup by [Sylow's first theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems) (or [Cauchy's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29)), and this is normal, [because it has index $2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_subgroup#Properties), and thus unique, by [Sylow's second theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems#Sylow_theorems). (Thanks a bunch to  Marc van Leeuwen for pointing out an ambiguity in a previous version.)

Comment: Just a caveat "normal, and thus unique" might suggest something horribly wrong to the naive reader. _Sylow subgroups_ that happen to be normal are the unique subgroups of their order, because all Sylow subgroups are conjugated to each other.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, ok, I will edit to avoid possible misunderstandings. Thanks!

Comment: Of course, a cyclic group of order $10$ is small enough that someone who doesn't know any of these theorems could just inspect the group, find all elements of order $5$, and observe that they all generate the same cyclic subgroup.